# Pyinstaller: Cannot open shared object libpython3.5m.so.1.0

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to create an executable for my Python application using PyInstaller. There are no errors when creating the executable, but when I subsequently try to run it, the following error occurs: 
`[6439] Error loading Python lib '~/PycharmProjects/CetPar/ceteris_paribus/control/build/controller/libpython3.5m.so.1.0': dlopen: ~/PycharmProjects/CetPar/ceteris_paribus/control/build/controller/libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I have already tried exporting multiple versions of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable, but this does not seem to have any effect. Trying to find the shared object by running the `locate libpython3.5m.so.1.0` command results in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0`, but adding `/usr/lib/` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` path does not work. I suspect this has something to do with the installation location of my python interpreters, but I have been unable to find anything. Furthermore, I noticed that PyInstaller also creates a `/dist/` directory, and the shared object file can be found here.

I am running elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki

Does anyone have any suggestions about things I can still try?

Answer (score 10):

There should be two folders `dist` and `build` in project folder after running pyinstaller. Copy `dist/controller` content into `build/controller` directory:

```
cp -r ./dist/controller/* build/controller
```

Comment: Man that works, but could you share some knowledge why? Or a link to a decent read on that topic (pytinstaller's docs are okay'ish at best imho)

Comment: @Gameplay sorry I don't remember any details and I have no any links to share...

Answer (score 0):

When using pyinstaller make sure to use the flag -F to make it a standalone executable

```
pyinstaller -F main.py
```

Then, after the build is complete, you'll find your standalone executable inside the dist directory(not the build directory)